# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'

Tags: aws-lambda

I got a following packaged Lamba code in zip file:

```
.
├── lambda_function.py
└── python
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── bin
    ├── certifi
    ├── certifi-2022.12.7.dist-info
    ├── certifi-2023.5.7.dist-info
    ├── charset_normalizer
    ├── charset_normalizer-3.1.0.dist-info
    ├── datadog
    ├── datadog-0.45.0.dist-info
    ├── datadog_api_client
    ├── datadog_api_client-2.11.0.dist-info
    ├── dateutil
    ├── idna
    ├── idna-3.4.dist-info
    ├── python_dateutil-2.8.2.dist-info
    ├── requests
    ├── requests-2.28.2.dist-info
    ├── requests-2.31.0.dist-info
    ├── six-1.16.0.dist-info
    ├── six.py
    ├── typing_extensions-4.5.0.dist-info
    ├── typing_extensions.py
    ├── urllib3
    ├── urllib3-1.26.15.dist-info
    └── urllib3-2.0.3.dist-info
```

I was trying to import and use requests inside my code like that:
 `import requests`

However AWS Lambda still shows the following alert when I try to import it inside my AWS Lambda:
 `[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function' Traceback (most recent call last):`

Here is how I zipped my Lambda package:
`cd deploy  zip -r ../function.zip *`